# To make sure the dates in the webtable are already sorted

Tags: java, selenium

I have one column in the webtable which contains dates (they are already sorted from latest to older).
Now my test case is to prove that dates are already sorted in the webtable.

By this code I will get all the dates to the list variable:

```
 List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
```

How I can prove this list is sorted and displayed in the UI?

Comment: Simply verify that you get the expected text in the expected cells once sorted. If you don't know the dates in advance, then start by writing a proper test case with some dates matching the bounds and the specific cases to consider.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
```

You can proceed ahead to split the problem and solve somewhat like this. This is just a method of doing it, ideally, would expect you to write code for it:

1. You have a `List<WebElement> rows` and you need to construct a `List<String> dates`  from it. Iterate over the `rows` and do a `.getText()` to add to the `dates`.
2. Create a method `compareDates(String d1, String d2)` that given two string dates compares in whatever format it is in your UI and returns 0,1,-1 as a compareTo method does.
3. Iterate over the newly created list `dates` as in (1) and then assert adjacent comparisons

   ```
   Assertion.assertTrue(compareDates(dates.get(i),dates.get(i+1)) == 0);
   ```

**Note**: The above operations can be done on a `List<Date>` instead of `List<String>` as well where in you can use the java built-in comparison methods to compare two dates. Thanks to @JeffC for pointing this out in comments.

Comment: Don't create a `List` of `String`, use `Date` provided by Java. That way you can use the built-in comparison methods already provided by Java. Writing your own means you have to debug it, etc. which takes more time.

Comment: @JeffC The reason I had to mention List<String> was that the dates format displayed in the UI is not described in the question. Otherwise, I would have preferred that as well. Anyway editing the point. The intention was to use compareTo only, built-in or overridden should just be part of time one can invest.